# Wrap python program into a GUI

Tags: python, user-interface

Right now I have a program that is asking the user to answer two questions then is generating an html file. It is getting done in the terminal window right now. The problem is if the user wants to change the answer to the first question they have to restart the program. Is there a simple python library or another way to wrap the program in a gui so basically a GUI pops up asks the user to enter into there answers to these two questions and fills in the variables in the program already?

```
outfile = open("hello.txt", 'w' )
questions=raw_input('What is the question')
answers= raw_input('What is the answer: ')
with outfile as myfile:
   myfile.write(questions)
   myfile.write(answers)
outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another loop that asks the user for an input to either escape or continue the loop.
pseudo-code
    
    `tryagain = True
    while tryagain:
        #your example possibly using "with"
        if raw_input ('try again y/n') != 'y':
            tryagain = False`